# Writing a generic binder in Go

Tags: go, bind, argument-passing

Consider the following function -- a binder of the second argument.

```
func bindSecond(value interface{}, f func(a interface{}, b interface{})) func (c interface{}) {
    return func(arg interface{}) {
        f(arg, value)
    }
}
```

Consider a function

```
func f(x int, y int) {}
```

When trying to use it as a parameter in binder, go compiler says:

```
cannot use f (type func(int, int)) as type func(interface {}, interface {}) in argument to bindSecond.
```

Could you please suggest me the proper way of implementing binders in go (golang)?

Answer (score 4):

Replace `interface{}` with `int` and it will work.

Or, more to the point, try to find a solution to your original problem using the features Go provides, instead of trying to force a solution from a different paradigm.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Sure, if I replace interface{} with int<, it will work. But it won't be a general solution anymore. I am looking for general binder that can be used with all types (note, that its behavior is independent from types)

Comment: My entire point is that you shouldn't be asking "how to make a binder in Go", you should be asking "how to solve this specific problem in Go".

Comment: This is more generally a question of "how do I make Go behave as a generic language." The answer is that Go is not a generic language. Go only has specific types. This wasn't an oversight; the Go team designed it this way on purpose. You can argue whether they made a good or bad choice, but fighting it will just produce horrible Go.

Answer (score 4):

I see what you're trying to do, some templates, right? But this is not going to work this way. Your `f func(a interface{}, b interface{})` argument is not an interface, so it must be of the matching type. You could achieve what you want by passing `f interface{}` and then manipulate it with `reflect` package.

Some naive [example](http://play.golang.org/p/poYw2pWSf4):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

func bindSecond(value interface{}, f interface{}) func(c interface{}) {
    return func(arg interface{}) {
        reflect.ValueOf(f).Call([]reflect.Value{reflect.ValueOf(arg), reflect.ValueOf(value)})
    }
}

func main() {
    sum := func(x int, y int) { fmt.Println(x + y) }
    inc := bindSecond(1, sum)
    inc(10)
}

// Prints 11
```

Doable, but not very pretty. And panics in *runtime* if anything unexpected happens, for example `f` is not callable and doesn't take exactly two arguments. Or you pass a wrong type to `inc`. Complier won't help you anymore.